# Почему не работает MediaRecorder?

Tags: java, android, аудио

Имеется такой код, с помощью которого я записываю данные с микрофона:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();               
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);             
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);                          
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);


try {
   mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}
mRecorder.start();
```

Так вот, при вызове метода start() получаю такой икзэпшн(на большинстве устройств):

```
E/AudioRecording: prepare() failed
E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-3
Process: music.player.musicplayer.audio.media.fm.video.radio.video.songs.equalizer.apps.free.android.lalala.download.search, PID: 7401
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
    at musicplayer.audioplayer.equalizer.mp3player.activity.ShazamActivity$1$1.run(ShazamActivity.java:100)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Comment: А разрешение на использование микрофона приложением запрашивается?

Comment: @dimxenon Конечно запрашивается